# How to draw custom view in NSStatusBar?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

I currently have a `NSStatusBar` with a `NSStatusBarItem` with a title displaying. But I wan't to replace the title/text with a custom `NSView`. How can I do that?

I currently have:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    let statusBar = NSStatusBar.system
    statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
    statusBarItem.button?.title = "My Menu Bar App"
}
```

Let's say I wan't to replace the title with the following:

```
let view = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.yellow.cgColor
```

How can I achieve that? I tried to add it as a subview to the button, with no luck.

Comment: Add the view to the subviews of the button

Comment: @vadian As I wrote: " I tried to add it as a subview to the button, with no luck."

Comment: The reason is something else: Unlike `UIView` you have to enable the layer in `NSView` with `view.wantsLayer = true`. Consider also that the height of the custom view is restricted to the height of the status bar.

Comment: I have added `.wantsLayer = true` to both the view and the button, but still nothing showing. Just a blank clickable square, but don't see any color.

Comment: I'm also using the `statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)` for a fixed size.

Comment: I tested quickly the configuration. It works, I see a yellow square

Comment: Could you maybe post the entire thing as an answer or a gist, so I can compare? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Create a strong reference to the status item on the top level of the class

  ```
  let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
  ```
- in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` enable the layer and add the view to the subviews of the button

  ```
  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

      let view = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 22, height: 22))
      view.wantsLayer = true
      view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.yellow.cgColor
      statusItem.button?.addSubview(view)

  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you! It works. My issue was that I was setting `view.wantsLayer = true` after `view.layer?.backgroundColor`. It has to go before to work.